How can I assign different IAM roles to two containers in the same ECS Task?
I have an ECS task which involves two containers running in a sidecar pattern. Per Amazon documentation, this is recommended for my use case where the containers share a lifecycle and need to run on the same host.
Under the principle of least privilege, I would like to give each of the containers a different IAM role with permissions scoped to its particular needs. To be specific, one container needs to be able to access S3 and SQS, while the other does not need to access any external resources.
Unfortunately, I can't find any documentation on a way to assign an IAM role to one container in an ECS task but not another. Is it possible to do this? If so, how?
(I'm using Terraform for this project, so any help using a Terraform example would be especially helpful.)

That's not possible using ECS role assignment. The roles are assigned at the task level, not the container level.

Currently, container-specific IAM roles are not directly supported in Amazon ECS as of now. The IAM task role (taskRoleArn) is assigned at the task level, and it applies to all containers in the task definition.
If you need container-specific permissions you need to separate ECS Tasks: Run each container in its own ECS task definition, each with its own taskRoleArn.
or you can assume Roles Dynamically: Use the primary IAM role to assume other roles as needed, but this adds complexity to your code, So basically, you need to give them a role, then within the code, you need to assume another role.
